# PHP notice Undefined index for magmi disabler

Tags: php, plugins, magmi

I have setup magmi with item disabler. And i got PHP notice: Undefined index: ITEM_SID in /home/mywebsite/www/public_html/magmi/plugins/extra/itemprocessors/itemdisabler/magmi_itemdisabler_plugin.php on line 65

This is the my code for item disabler

```
<?php class Magmi_ItemdisablerPlugin extends Magmi_GeneralImportPlugin {


protected $_dcols=array();  
protected $magentoSortableAttributes = array(); 


public function getPluginInfo()

{
    return array("name"=>"Magmi Magento Item Disabler",
                         "author"=>"RIS",
                         "version"=>"1.0.0");
}      

public function afterImport()
{
    $this->log("Running Item Disabler Plugin","info");
    $this->disableItems();
    return true;
}

public function getPluginParams($params)
{
    return array();
}

public function isRunnable()
{
    return array(true,"");
}

public function initialize($params)
{
}

public function disableItems()
{       

    $this->datasource = $this->getDataSource();
    $nitems=$this->lookup();


    if($nitems>0)
    {
        $datasource_item_sids = array();    
        $this->resetSkuStats();

        //intialize store id cache
        $this->callPlugins("datasources,itemprocessors","startImport");

        //initializing item processors
        $cols=$this->datasource->getColumnNames();
        $this->log(count($cols),"columns");
        //$this->callPlugins("itemprocessors","processColumnList",$cols);


        //Pack the datasource sids into an array
        $i = 0;
        while(($item=$this->datasource->getNextRecord())!==false && $i++ <= $nitems)
        {   
            if (isset($item['STYLE_SID']) && $this->isConfigurable($item['ATTR']))
            {
                array_push($datasource_item_sids, $item['STYLE_SID']);  
            }
                array_push($datasource_item_sids, $item['ITEM_SID']);

            if($i == $nitems) {
                break; 
            }
        }

        if(count($datasource_item_sids) > 0) {

            //Convert skus to comma seperated values.
            //$datasource_item_sids = "'" . implode("','",$datasource_item_sids) . "'";             

            //Load in Database Helpers
            require_once(realpath(dirname( __FILE__ ) )."/../../../../inc/dbhelper.class.php");
            //var_dump($this->_magmiconfig->load()->get("DATABASE","host","localhost"));
            $db = new DBHelper();
            $host=$this->_magmiconfig->load()->get("DATABASE","host","localhost");
            $dbname=$this->_magmiconfig->load()->get("DATABASE","dbname","magento");
            $user=$this->_magmiconfig->load()->get("DATABASE","user");
            $pass=$this->_magmiconfig->load()->get("DATABASE","password");
            $debug=$this->_magmiconfig->load()->get("DATABASE","debug");
            $conn=$this->_magmiconfig->load()->get("DATABASE","connectivity","net");
            $port=$this->_magmiconfig->load()->get("DATABASE","port","3306");
            $socket=$this->_magmiconfig->load()->get("DATABASE","unix_socket");
            $prefix=$this->_magmiconfig->load()->get("DATABASE","table_prefix");
            $db->initDb($host,$dbname,$user,$pass,$port,$socket,$conn,$debug);

            //Setup tables
            $ea     = $prefix!=""?$prefix."eav_attribute":"eav_attribute";
            $cpe     = $prefix!=""?$prefix."catalog_product_entity":"catalog_product_entity";
            $cpei     = $prefix!=""?$prefix."catalog_product_entity_int":"catalog_product_entity_int";

            //Get "status" attribute_id
            $status_attr_id = "SELECT attribute_id FROM $ea WHERE attribute_code = 'status'";               
            $result = $db->selectAll($status_attr_id);  
            if (count($result) == 1) {
                $attribute_id = $result[0]['attribute_id'];
            }
            unset($result);

            //Get all active items
            $sql = "SELECT e.sku, e.entity_id FROM $cpei i
                              INNER JOIN $cpe e ON
                              e.entity_id = i.entity_id
                              WHERE attribute_id=?
                              AND i.value = 1";
            $all_magento_items = $db->selectAll($sql, array($attribute_id));

            //Setup the magento_skus array for easy processing.
            $magento_skus = array();
            foreach($all_magento_items as $item)
            {
                $magento_skus[$item['sku']] = $item['entity_id'];
            }


            //process the array, move anything thats in the datasource.
            foreach($datasource_item_sids as $sku)
            {
                if(isset($magento_skus[$sku]))
                {
                    unset($magento_skus[$sku]);
                }
            }

            if(!empty($magento_skus))
            {               
                foreach($magento_skus as $sku => $id)
                {

                    $this->log("Disabling Item Id $id with SKU: $sku", "info"); 
                    $this->update("
                        UPDATE $cpei i
                        INNER JOIN $cpe e ON
                        e.entity_id = i.entity_id
                        SET VALUE = '2'
                        WHERE attribute_id = ?
                        AND i.value = 1
                        AND e.sku=?", array($attribute_id, $sku));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //If the Datasource contains all Magento's items.
                $this->log('All items present in datasource.  No items to disable.', "info");       
            }

            $db->exitDb();
            unset($db);

        }

    }

}   

public function isConfigurable($field) {
    $attributes = explode('|',$field);

    $conf_attributes = '';

    foreach($attributes as $attribut) {
        $att = explode(':',$attribut);
        if(count($att) != 2) {
            return false;
            break;

        }
        if($att[1] == '') {
            return false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return true;

}
```

}

Any idea how i can resolve this?

Comment: Check your values, make sure they are passed to the functions they are needed, It's really just a matter of starting from the beginning and then each time you send the required data on, you stop at the receiving function / place and check if they have gotten the data, and then you just repeat this until you've made sure that all the data has gotten through all the required places.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if that element is set before using it:

```
while(($item=$this->datasource->getNextRecord())!==false && $i++ <= $nitems)
{   
    if (isset($item['STYLE_SID']) && $this->isConfigurable($item['ATTR']))
    {
        array_push($datasource_item_sids, $item['STYLE_SID']);  
    }
    if (isset($item['ITEM_SID']){
        array_push($datasource_item_sids, $item['ITEM_SID']);
    }
    if($i == $nitems) {
        break; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have try your code, and i got syntax error. Then i added  
&& $this->isConfigurable($item['ATTR'])), 
like this:

' while(($item=$this->datasource->getNextRecord())!==false && $i++ <= $nitems)
{   
    if (isset($item['STYLE_SID']) && $this->isConfigurable($item['ATTR']))
    {
        array_push($datasource_item_sids, $item['STYLE_SID']);  
    }
    if (isset($item['ITEM_SID']) && $this->isConfigurable($item['ATTR'])){
        array_push($datasource_item_sids, $item['ITEM_SID']);
    }
    if($i == $nitems) {
        break; 
    }
}
I dont know if that was right code but it worked for me.

Comment: not necessarilly that; I missed a ")" in this line: "if (isset($item['ITEM_SID']){". It should be "if (isset($item['ITEM_SID'])){"